# How to aggregate different RSS Feed in a single Feed

Tags: rss, aggregate, feed

i have a website (based on liferay) that produces more than 300 Feeds (one for each community). I need to expose a single Feed, but i need that feed to come from my server (that means that if my site is www.mysyte.com, the feed Must be www.mysyte.com/rss.xml).
How can i do that?

Comment: I hope this link help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991392/liferays-rss-portlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if anyone is interested in the answer to this question. I created a simple function in php that did the trick. If anyine needs help on the topic i will detail the answer with code examples

Comment: Man, why no actual code answer? :/ By now, I bet you don't even work where you used to work, but the answer would have still been helpful just to see how someone approached the issue :(