# Liferay's RSS portlet

Tags: rss, liferay-6

My project requires Liferay's RSS portlet to read feeds from Liferay CMS. Could someone please guide me how to achieve this? I am using Liferay 6.0.6.
I scanned the internet but could not find relevant material.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel. Click on Web Content from the left. Click on Feed tab. Here you can create your feed. To quickly get started, just give a name and in the target friendly url textbox give the value of a liferay page in the same community. For example if you have a page called http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home, then give the target friendly url as /web/guest/home

Once the feed is created. Click on edit from Actions button in front of the feed that you just created. You will see it has generated a feed url for you. Use that feed url in the RSS portlet.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to see the feed URL now. Could you let me know how to use this URL in RSS portlet?

Comment: Hi, I pressed the configuration button and added the URL. However now I am getting the following error:

http://10.16.142.250:8085/group/maasdam/reports/-/journal/rss/REPORTS?doAsGroupId=12909&refererPlid=12919&_15_groupId=12909 cannot be found.

Comment: Can you see if the feed is working by copying the feed url and pasting it in browser. Do you see the content?

Comment: Where would this feed creation be found in 6.2? An update to this answer would be great and a small note on which version the earlier method referred to.